# React CSS Webpack Hashing & Usage with semantic-ui-sass, semantic-ui-react

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, semantic-ui

If my application is using

```
test: /\.s+([ac])ss?/,
use: [
    {
        loader: 'style-loader'
    },

    {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
            modules: true,
            localIdentName: '[hash:base64:7]'
        }
    },

    {
        loader: 'sass-loader',
        options: {
            sourceMap: !isProductionEnvironment
        }
    },

    {
        loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
        options: {
            resources: 'src/styles/variables.scss'
        }
    }
]
```

webpack configuration to load css and sass, semantic-ui-sass package gets hashed upon import, is there a way to comfortably use `semantic-ui-react` package to decode those hashes?

Alternatively I am trying to use the

```
:global {
    @import '~semantic-ui-sass/semantic-ui';
}
```

`:global` directive so that it could be used globally, but the webpack compiler then does not resolve icons and fonts from that package:

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../../icons/outline-icons.woff2'`

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved the following issue by manually handling font icons and images by providing the semantic variables with their path:

```
<src/styles/global.scss>

    $icons-font-path: '~semantic-ui-sass/icons';
    $flags-image-path: '~semantic-ui-sass/images';
    :global {
        @import '~semantic-ui-sass/semantic-ui';
    }
```